Facing cors issue after making successful api call in abp application
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'serversiteurl//api/services/app/QklyProcessEngine/CallProcess' from origin 'clientsiteurl' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Getting this above error, after making a api call from client and after 3 mins i'm getting the errors, every time i call that specific api. I'm so confused to conclude whether it's an api error or cors error.
NOTE : My cors configuration is perfect.
Every time I get cors issue, i get this below server error.
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled. 
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTransaction.CreateSavepointAsync(String name, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTransaction.CreateSavepointAsync(String name, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
    at Qkly.EntityFrameworkCore.QklyDbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\Quickly-application\Quickly-application\src\Qkly.EntityFrameworkCore\EntityFrameworkCore\QklyDbContext.cs:line 6200 
    at Abp.EntityFramework...


Check server response in Developer Console in your browser - I guess you'll see 500 status code and ServerError page from your server.
And usually these error pages do not include any CORS headers or other such things.
So, you have server API error. Inability of client JS to correctly read this error (due to CORS) is secondary.

thanks, if i correct my api error, will it be fixed?

yes, unless your API will have other error (including CORS)

okay, if it is server error then why cors policy issue occurs that confused me to find the root cause and both are unrelated.
For other server errors, this cors policy issue is not coming.

its your code, its hard to make full diagnostic with only one stacktrace :)

Thanks, it was happened due server time out. I have planned to increase server time out.
do you have any idea?

Sure. Rewrite your DB and/or app so it doesn't take so long to execute the query. Or, your next step will be "upgrade server" :)

ok, how long a http request wait for it's response?
